# Custom Console Components Not Appearing in Console

Tags: custom-console-components

[image]I have tried to implement custom console components for the Work Orders object, but cannot get them to appear in the console. I am trying to add simple 'out of the box' actions, Look up and Related Lists, as a stack in the left sidebar subtab. Custom Console tabs are enabled in our settings and I have all the permissions for our experience.

PX Width is set to 500, but have tried ranging from 30-999. I have tried auto size and manual heights.

I have hit save on both the Custom console page then again on the page layout editor. They are not collapsed on the page, they simply are not there. I gave it overnight last night incase it takes time to appear, but nothing still.

Is there anyone out there who can help?!
[image: Image of Work Order]
[image: Image of Case w/ custom component Red arrow indicates what I'm trying to add to work order]

Comment: What do you mean by custom console page? Do you mean a visual force page? Can you provide a screenshot of your console app (the full window) and maybe put something in using paint to demonstrate what you expect and show us what you are actually seeing?

Comment: By custom console page, I mean the page where you customize the console.

Comment: @gNerb Images uploaded!

Comment: did you implemented flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes in component?

Comment: Is it a lightning component or a custom console component. Those are very different things.

Comment: @ManjotSingh Where would I implement that?

Comment: @gNerb A custom console component. Trying to create from Setup->Object Manager-> Work Orders->Page Layouts->Custom Console Components

Comment: @BennettC A quick look shows that you don't need to implement flexipage, that's only for lightning components. I was able to find what you're trying to do and I'm running some checks now to see if I can find anything out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the answer is that those types of components are not supported in lightning. if you navigate back to a console app in the classic view, you'll see your components are exactly where you would expect.

[Reference](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/service_components/units/service_components_comfortable)

> Salesforce has two different desktop user interfaces: Lightning Experience and Salesforce Classic. This module is designed for Salesforce Classic.

Comment: Oh boy. In my haste to customize I didn't read the most important line!!

Thanks a ton @gNerb !!

Comment: @BennettC Glad I could help. If you found this answer helpful, please remember to mark it as accepted so that other's who find this post can easily identify it as correct and so that others who are looking to answer questions don't waste their time trying to solve your problem even after it's already been solved.